# How to Stop Catching a Specific Exception in C#

Tags: c#, exception

**Question**

I am assigning values to labels (100.. labels) some string values (all values are different)

Example:

```
Label1.Text=Excel.Worksheet1.Cells[1,1];
Label2.Text=Excel.Worksheet1.Cells[1,2];
Label3.Text=Excel.Worksheet1.Cells[1,3];
Label4.Text=Excel.Worksheet1.Cells[1,4];
........
........
........
Label100.Text=Excel.Worksheet1.Cells[1,5];
```

While assigning some values to labels.. some Excel cell values may be null.. It catches an exception (say NULL-Value Exception). Here in this case I want **not to catch any specified exception.**

It should proceed its execution without catching the given exception (null exception).

- Here I can't use `try {..} catch {..}` for all lines of code..
- Program execution should not jump / miss any line of code..

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Why not just use if-else statements to check for null?

Comment: Assigning a `Text` to `null` should not throw exception, what's the actual problem?

Comment: Use a default catch with if statements checking the type, but you're error checking should be better tuned than *if anything is thrown run this logic*...

Comment: What throws the Exception - the Label#.Text setter or the Excel.Worksheet.Cells indexer?

Comment: @GarethCornish Probably the latter. Setters don't usually throw exceptions.

Comment: Actually it reads many Excel files (As Input to my Program), some times the value may be null in specified cell. hence it catches an null values exception.
Actually i don't want to catch this null exception. Flow should continue..reading data.

Comment: @Admin - Adding conditional logic to a generic catch that results in no action would achieve exactly that. It would likely be better suggested that you setup explicit catches for the exception types you _don't_ want to catch that do nothing and then other catches to react as your application requires.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To stop **Null exception** i used following technique.

```
Label1.Text=(Excel.Worksheet1.Cells[1,1].value ?? "Some_Str";
Label2.Text=(Excel.Worksheet1.Cells[1,2].value ?? "Some_Str";
Label3.Text=(Excel.Worksheet1.Cells[1,3].value ?? "Some_Str";
Label4.Text=(Excel.Worksheet1.Cells[1,4].value ?? "Some_Str";
```

If excel has some empty fields its retaken by some other string

if null then Some_Str other wise its value.
Simple.

Answer (score 0):

If the error is being thrown by the Label1.Text setter, you could try the `??` construct:

```
Label1.Text = Excel.Worksheet1.Cells[1,1] ?? string.Empty;
```

This will set the value to `Excel.Worksheet1.Cells[1,1]` if that is not null, and to `string.Empty` if it is.

If the error is being thrown by the `Excel.Worksheet1.Cells[1,1]` indexer, you'll need to write a method to contain your setting logic:

```
// Assuming the Excel object is global and static; otherwise you'll need to 
// include a reference to that too
private string GetExcelWorksheetValue(int index1, int index2){
    try{
        return Excel.Worksheet1.Cells[index1, index2];
    } catch(NullReferenceException err){ // Or whatever type of Exception you're trying to catch
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Then change each line in your process to:

```
Label4.Text = GetExcelWorksheetValue(1,4);
```

Comment: But isn't the OP explicitly trying *not* to catch NullReferenceExceptions?

Comment: It isn't possible to prevent an exception of any type from interrupting the process without catching and handling it. I understood from the question that the OP is trying to prevent having to handle the Exception by breaking out of his code.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you provide a condition for each case where the cell's value is `null` and use the empty string `""` as the `labelX.txt` instead? It sounds like its throwing the exception when your assigning a label value to null.

Example:

```
if(Excel.Worksheet1.Cells[1,1] != null{
    Label1.Text = Excel.Worksheet1.Cells[1,1]
}
else{
    Label1.Text = ""
}...
```